# I want to calculate warranty expiry date in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xampp

I had already created responsive web page to submit data with some calculation with date to give number of days between two date's`(EX: Start Date:29/OCT/2018 End Date: 07/NOV/2018)` and now it gives number of days`(No. of days = 9)` while submitting but I want the days to be reduced when date also increases. Please help to give some ideas regarding this

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetDays(){
                var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("end_date").value);
                var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("added_date").value);
                return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
        }

        function cal(){
        if(document.getElementById("end_date")){
            document.getElementById("calc").value=GetDays();
        }  
    }



    </script>
</head>
<body>

          <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Invoice Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="added_date" name="added_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" readonly/>
                    </div>

          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>End Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="end_date" name="end_date" onchange="cal()" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>Warranty</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="calc" name="calc"value="" readonly/>
            </div>
          </div>






</body>
```

Comment: u need to work with current date and time then it will be reduced

Comment: I have given current date only but  gives me result while submission thereafter it displays only the record saved in the database

Comment: Your pickdt will be current date. And the Date you'll use in db-query will be different. Check your query once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this and understand the concept:**

```js
  var todaydate = new Date();
   var day = todaydate.getDate();
   var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
   var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
   var datestring =month  + "/" +  day+ "/" + year;
   
   document.getElementById("added_date").value = datestring;
  
  function GetDays(){
  
  
   
                var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("end_date").value);
                var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("added_date").value);
                
                
                
                 var dateDifference = Math.floor((Date.UTC(dropdt.getFullYear(), dropdt.getMonth(), dropdt.getDate()) - Date.UTC(pickdt.getFullYear(), pickdt.getMonth(), pickdt.getDate())) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

                return dateDifference;
        }

        function cal(){
        if(document.getElementById("end_date")){
            document.getElementById("calc").value=GetDays();
        }  
        
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Invoice Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="added_date" name="added_date" readonly/>
                    </div>

          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>End Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="end_date" name="end_date" onchange="cal()" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>Warranty</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="calc" name="calc"value="" readonly/>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and to display in a table you need to use date_diff(added_date,end_date) in query.

Answer (score 0):

As the remaining warranty is calculated from the current fate so you need to pass the current date,

```
var cuurent = new Date().getTime();

     return parseInt((dropdt - cuurent) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
```

Comment: Please give changes based on my code as i am a beginner i couldn't understand

Comment: Please see my code i have given the entire code with html content